# Who killed Nimrod?

Tags: midrash, avot-patriarch-fathers, pentateuch-chumash, esav, genesis-bereishith

I used  to think that Esav killed Nimrod and took the special garment that was originally Adam Harishon's. (Is this a Midrash?) But now I'm wondering if Avraham Avinu and Eliezer killed Nimrod during the battle against the four kings?
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirke_De-Rabbi_Eliezer) does indeed state that Esav killed Nimrod (ed. Higger ch. 31). This is also found in [Yalkut Shimoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yalkut_Shimoni) (Parashat Tol'dot 110) and Targum [Pseudo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60989/8775)-Jonathan (Parashat Tol'dot 25:27). It is further quoted by [Rabbenu Hayyim Paltiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Paltiel_(Paltiel_of_Falaise)) (Parashat Tol'dot 25:32) and [Rabbenu Bahya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahya_ben_Asher) (B'reshit 3:21)

You are also correct that there is a Midrash that Avraham killed Nimrod. This can be found in [Tanhuma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanhuma) (ed. Buber) Parashat Vayera (2), which identifies Nimrod with Amrafel, and states that Avraham killed him. This is also found in Yalkut Shimoni Yeshaya (511).

Comment: That's an answer. (FTR, Eruv. 53a cites the two opinions re. Nimord/Amrafel.)

Comment: @Oliver That does not seem overly relevant. Avraham could've killed Nimrod without him being Amrafel, and he coulve been Amrafel without Avraham killing him.

Comment: and that's why it's only a comment, pertaining to the point re. Chazal in Tan. identifying them as the same person