# What is the oldest extant source which attributes Targum Pseudo-Jonathan to Yonasan Ben Uziel?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, tannaim, targumin

There’s an impressive [list of proofs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60986/) that what’s commonly called Targum Yonasan on the Chumash was not, in fact, written by Yonasan Ben Uziel.

Where did the rumor start that it was actually written by him? What’s the earliest source we have which attributes this particular translation to Yonasan Ben Uziel?

Comment: In my answer to your linked question I brought from Moses Mendelssohn his theory how the misattribution started. Others followed his theory, and he seems to be the first to suggest it, but he doesn't (as far as I know) give a date for when this started.

Comment: The [Jewish Encylopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14248-targum) claims that the earliest source in which this Targum is ascribed to Targum Yonatan ben Uziel is the Recanati, in 14th century Italy (long page; search "Recanati") but I'm not sure what their source is. (Azariah de Rossi as linked in robev's answer mentions Recanati doing so but I don't see that he claims Recanati was the first.)

Comment: @Rish Certainly a start. Why don’t you post it as an answer?

Comment: cc @robev ^^^^^

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen that before posting.

Comment: You have to wonder how many "old references" are just cases of later editions "unpacking" the acronym ת"י incorrectly. cc @רבותמחשבות

Comment: @DoubleAA 100%. That's why I need to check older versions of them...

Answer (score 3):

I just read this somewhere by chance today, and only later noticed this question! According to [Rabbi Refael Binyamin Posen](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%96%D7%9F), the author of Parshegen, in footnote 30 [here](http://shaalvim.co.il/torah/maayan-article.asp?id=150#_ftn31), it was [Rabbi Menachem Rekanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_Recanati).

However, after a bit of searching, this is not necessarily the case. A longer discussion of this is brought in Shem Hagedolim, and although he concludes that it was not authored by Yonasan Ben Uziel, he brings some versions of Tosfos that refer to this Targum as Yonasan, as well as some other sources (Hebrew). However, he also brings the Rekanti, so most likely everyone has been relying on him... Here's his opening paragraph, where he notes some of the sources:

> תרגום יונתן על התורה נדפס פעמים. וראיתי למהרש"א בחידושי אגדות ריש מגילה כתב וז"ל ומקמיה אונקלוס הוה יונתן אלא שלא היה יונתן חש לפרש התורה או מטעמא דלקמן דמפרשא מילתא ולא הוה מפרש רק נביאי' דאיכא מילי דמסתמן עד שבא אונקלוס ופי' לדורו גם התורה עכ"ל. וכד הוינא טליא לא ידענא מאי קאמר דהרי יונתן פי' התורה. והתוספות בסוף חגיגה הזכירוהו שכתבו תרגם יונתן כרכושתא וסלמנדרא. וכן הרב הנמקי סוף פ"ב דמציעא כתב סיכויין רב יוסף בני חי תרגם יונתן וכו'. וכן מהר"ם ריקאנטי שהיה בדור הרשב"א מזכירו בספר יונתן על התורה:

Comment: Which coincides with the unsourced claim by Jewish Encyclopedia [mentioned by Rish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104123/what-is-the-oldest-extant-source-which-attributes-targum-pseudo-jonathan-to-yona/104203#comment347361_104123). Great find!

Comment: @DonielF just edited to improve...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some sources that it was written by Yonasan ben Uziel

The Shita Mekubetzes in Bava Kama 3b seems to indicate that Targum Yonasan was written on the Torah [not sure how this works with Megilla 3] here are his words
כדמתרגם רב יוסף. נקט רב יוסף לפי שהיה בקי בתרגום שיש כמה עניני תרגום תרגום יונתן ותרגום אונקלוס והם פירושי התורה ולא כדפירש בעלמא לפי שהיה סגיא נהור לא היה מדבר אלא בלשון תרגום. רבינו ישעיה ז"ל:

Other Rishonim bring his peirush on Chumash and ascribe it to yonasan see Daas zekainim Bamidbar 12:7

Mizrachi Vayikra 11:3 brings a quote from Aruch stating that Yonatan ben Uziel wrote targum yonasan regarding a pasuk in sefer Vayikra

מזרחי על ויקרא פרק יא פסוק ג
ובעל הערוך כתב בערך טלף, "ושוסעת שסע תרגום ומטלפא טלפין. וכל מפרסת פרסה תרגם יונתן דמטלפא טליפין", כאלו אמר, שפירושו מטלפא לפי אנקלוס היא השוסעת, ולפי יונתן בן עוזיאל היא המפרסת

Also, malbim brings from Yonasan b"u regarding a pasuk in Shemos

מלבים על שמות פרק כא פסוק כח <ק>
סקול יסקל השור ולא יאכל את בשרו. פי' אף אם שחטו קודם סקילה אחר שנגמר דינו אסור באכילה, וכן פי' בגמ' (ב"ק מא, קדושין נו ובכ"מ) וכן תרגום יונתן ב"ע ולא יתנכס למיכל ית בשריה,

There are too many examples to count. Google or search for the name yonasan ben Uziel in Rishonim and you will see that they reference him by his full name on pesukim in the Chumash.

Also type in the following acronyms

יוב"ע
יב"ע
the theory that the printers confused ת"י
to mean targum yonasan when it really menat targum yerushalmi is a good one if the letters were just, tuv and yud
however, it is unlikely to hold water if the acronyms were the 2 i referenced above